# Pandas dataframe values equality test

Tags: python, pandas

Another Pandas question!

I am writing some unit tests that test two data frames for equality, however, the test does not appear to look at the values of the data frame, only the structure:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))

print df1
print df2
self.assertItemsEqual(df1, df2)
```

-->True

Do I need to convert the data frames to another data structure before asserting equality?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ah, of course there is a solution for this already:

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
```

**EDIT:** pandas.util.testing was [deprecated in 2020](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html). From version 1.0 forward, use:

```
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal
```

The API documentation for assert_frame_equal can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html)

Answer (score 6):

While assert_frame_equal is useful in unit tests, I found the following useful on analysis as one might want to further check which values are not equal:
`df1.equals(df2)`

Answer (score 4):

Also numpy's utilities work:

```
import numpy.testing as npt

npt.assert_array_equal(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [62]: import numpy as np

In [63]: import pandas as pd

In [64]: np.random.seed(30)

In [65]: df_old = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,5))

In [66]: df_old
Out[66]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -1.264053  1.527905 -0.970711  0.470560 -0.100697
1  0.303793 -1.725962  1.585095  0.134297 -1.106855
2  1.578226  0.107498 -0.764048 -0.775189  1.383847
3  0.760385 -0.285646  0.538367 -2.083897  0.937782

In [67]: np.random.seed(30)

In [68]: df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,5))

In [69]: df_new
Out[69]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -1.264053  1.527905 -0.970711  0.470560 -0.100697
1  0.303793 -1.725962  1.585095  0.134297 -1.106855
2  1.578226  0.107498 -0.764048 -0.775189  1.383847
3  0.760385 -0.285646  0.538367 -2.083897  0.937782

In [70]: df_old.equals(df_new) #Equality check here, returns boolean expression: True/False
Out[70]: True
```